# What is the MIME type of an EXIF JPEG file without a JFIF header?

Tags: format, jpeg, mime-types, iana

I have been looking at the IANA MIME type registry for [JPEG](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2046), and it seems that image/jpeg is only registered for the format following the JFIF standard. Therefore, from that, there is no MIME type for JPEG files with EXIF data and no JFIF header, am I correct?

If so, maybe I will contact IANA so that they change the definition so that JPEG is *either* following JFIF or EXIT format, no?